# Simple output from parent category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with this code in template page for WP.

```
<div id="content" role="main">
<?php

$query = array(
'post_type'      => 'post',
'category_name'  => 'jewellery-design',
'orderby'        => 'date',
'order'          => 'DESC'
);

$featured_home = new WP_Query( $query );

if( $featured_home->have_posts() ) {
?>


<div class="row">
    <?php while ( $featured_home->have_posts() ) : $featured_home->the_post();?>
     <span class="cat"><?php the_category(); ?> 
    <div class="col-3">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="featured-home-img" <?php
            if ( $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
                if ( $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'normal-bg' ) )
                    printf( ' style="background-image: url(%s);"', $image_src[0] );     
                }?>>

                <div class="blog-info-content">

                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <div class="obsah"><?php the_content(); ?></div>   </span>
                                    <p class="postmetadata">
Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> 
<strong>|</strong>
<?php edit_post_link('Edit','','<strong>|</strong>'); ?>  

            </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
</div>
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>    
      </div>
```

And  I am getting output like this:
[image]

But, i´d like to have output like this:
[image]

Can someone tell me how can I do it? Or may I use some plugin for Wordpress to make it easier for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I might think about sorting them into groups first, then re-looping over the sorted groups. I am a little rusty on Wordpress so I have set it up essentially, but all the functions/methods need to `return` values, not `echo`, so you will need to adjust that:

```
<?php
# Create base function
function getItemsByCategoryType($category)
{
    $query = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'category_name'  => $category,
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC'
    );
    # Get query
    $featured_home = new WP_Query($query);
    # Just stop if empty
    if(!$featured_home->have_posts())
        return false;
    # Set a default
    $array = array();
    while($featured_home->have_posts()){
        $featured_home->the_post();
        $thumbnail_id =  get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_src    =  ($thumbnail_id)? wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id,'normal-bg')) : false;
        # You are looking to store the category title as the key
        # That will isolate each group
        $array[the_category()][] = array(
            'thumb_id' => $thumbnail_id,
            'image' => $image_src,
            'permlink' => the_permalink(),
            'title' => the_title(),
            'content' => the_content(),
            'categories' => the_category(', '),
            'edit_mode' => edit_post_link('Edit','','<strong>|</strong>')
        );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    # Send back stored data as an array
    return $array;
}

# To use, get the data from your function    
$Items = getItemsByCategoryType('jewellery-design') ?>

<div id="content" role="main">
    <?php if(!empty($Items)): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($Items as $categories => $rows): ?>
        <span class="cat"><?php echo $categories ?>
            <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
            <div class="col-3">
                <a href="<?php echo $row['permlink'] ?>">
                    <div class="featured-home-img"<?php if(!empty($row['image'][0])) echo ' style="background-image: url('.$row['image'][0].');"' ?>>
                        <div class="blog-info-content">
                            <h3><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h3>
                            <div class="obsah">
                                <?php echo $row['content'] ?>
                            </div>
                            <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php echo $row['categories'] ?><strong>|</strong><?php $row['edit_mode'] ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </span>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

> **NOTE:** Just to reiterate, I am not up to speed on WP so you need to take the idea of what I am proposing and fixing it, specifically when it comes to returning values vs allowing the WP functions to `echo` content.

---

**EDIT:**

You want an array to come out of the function similar to:

```
Array (
    [ Fibre Collection ] => Array (
        [ 0 ] => Array (
            [ title ] => FIBRE_BRACELET
            [ content ] => etc...,
            etc...
        )
    ),
    [ Tetragon Collection ] => Array (
        [ 0 ] => Array (
            [ title ] => Test2
            [ content ] => etc...,
            etc...
        ),
        [ 1 ] => Array (
            [ title ] => TETRAGÓN_BRACELET
            [ content ] => etc...,
            etc...
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I´m not getting right output even when I tried your´s solution. Like still getting the same.

Comment: Are you returning the data from those functions? There are two loops in my script vs yours, it would be very unlikely that you’d get the exact same thing as before.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I found a solution by myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the output I needed. If this helps anyone :)

```
$cat_args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'parent' => 2
   );
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args=array(
      'showposts' => -1,
      'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
      if ($posts) {
        echo '<div class="test"><p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
          setup_postdata($post); ?>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" <?php the_content(); ?></a></p>
          <?php
        } // foreach($posts
      echo '</div>';}  // if ($posts
    } // foreach($categories
?>
```

The 'parent' => 2 means ID of parent category from which you want to get your posts.

Have a nice day.